# Webscraping cryptocurrency

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In this class I made a webscraper for a cryptocurrency website to get the name and the price of each currency. There are maybe API's that I can also use, but I thought it is better to gain some knowledge doing it with scraping.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

class Coins:

    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://www.coinbase.com/price"
        self.new_list = []

    # Check if I get a 200 status code and if so, create instance from bs4
    def get_response(self):
        self.response = requests.get(self.url)

        if self.response:
            print("Access granted")
            self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.response.text, 'lxml')
        else:
            print("Error")

    # Select the class and get the data
    def get_data(self):
        info = self.soup.find_all(class_="Header__StyledHeader-sc-1q6y56a-0 hZxUBM TextElement__Spacer-sc-18l8wi5-0 hpeTzd")
        # Here, I only want to get the name and the price of the crypto, I don't want to get other information and thats why I am using the modulo operator.
        for x,e in enumerate(info):
            if x % 3 == 2:
                # print("I dont need this information")
                pass
            else:
                self.new_list.append(e.text)

        return self.new_list

    # From the information that I got and appended into a list, make a dict
    def make_dict(self):
        self.my_dict = {self.new_list[x]:self.new_list[x + 1] for x in range(0, len(self.new_list), 2)}
        return self.my_dict

    # Save the data into a json file
    def save_data(self):
        with open('data.json','w') as output:
            json.dump(self.my_dict, output, indent=2)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Coins()
    test.get_response()
    test.get_data()
    test.make_dict()
    test.save_data()
```

One of my concern is: I try to access variables inside a method, is using `self` a good idea? For example in the method `save_data()`. I wanted to pass the function `get_data()` in `json.dump()` but it didn't work out. So I changed in `make_dict()` the variable to `self.my_dict` to access it in the method `save_data()` and it worked out, but is it a good practice or not at all?

This is my first time actually working with classes. I appreciate any feedback to improve myself.

Comment: The use of `I tried` in the first sentence can indicate that the code is not working as intended. Code review is a site where only working code is reviewed. Is this code working as expected?

Comment: Yes, it is working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternate implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
import re
import requests


class Coins:
    table_re = re.compile('^AssetTable__Table-')

    def __init__(self, url="https://www.coinbase.com/price"):
        self.url = url
        self.session = requests.Session()

    # Check if I get a 200 status code and if so, create instance from bs4
    def _get_response(self) -> BeautifulSoup:
        response = self.session.get(self.url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    # Select the class and get the data
    def get_data(self) -> dict:
        soup = self._get_response()
        table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': self.table_re})
        prices = {}
        for row in table.tbody.find_all('tr'):
            cells = row.find_all('td')
            if len(cells) < 6:
                continue
            name = cells[1].find('h4').text
            price = cells[2].find('h4').text
            prices[name] = price
        return prices
```

Note:

- Do not rely on long, terrible, possibly dynamically-generated CSS class names
- If you want to reuse this class to repeatedly fetch prices, then the members should be the session and the URL, and the data should be restricted to the function
- Don't write `access granted`. Other than it being corny, you should only throw an exception if there's a failure, not write to `stdout` if there's a success in the data retrieval method. Such progress indicators are best left to the calling function above.
- Just index into the cells. Don't use the modulus.

Comment: Thanks for your notes. I appreciate the work that you have done for me. I will use your feedback to improve my coding.